Allure steps are not displayed in report
I want to use io.qameta.allure.kotlin.Allure.step in my project for my tests and expect them to show in the report. But this is not happening, here is an code example:
        step("Create task") {
            client.createTask(task)
        }

These are my allure-related plugins and dependencies:
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "2.0.21"
    id("io.qameta.allure") version "2.12.0"
}

dependencies {
    // Other unrelated to Allure dependencies
    // ...
    // AspectJ Weaver
    runtimeOnly("org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.22.1")
    // JUnit
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.11.3")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.11.3")
    // Allure
    testImplementation("io.qameta.allure:allure-junit5:2.29.0")
    testImplementation("io.qameta.allure:allure-kotlin-commons:2.4.0")

}

After running tests and allureServe my report contains all the results, but steps are not included
